# Populating derived fields in an Angular Dart component

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I have a component that takes a single attribute. I want to populate a field in the component with a value that is derived from this attribute. I am running into the problem that the binding with the attribute has not happened when the code inside the constructor runs. How, then, do I set the value of the derived field?

Here is some code:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'tokens',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    cssUrl: './component.css',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const {
      'text' : '@text'
    }
)
class TokensComponent {
  String text;

  // Derived field.
  List<Token> tokens = new List<Token>();

  TokensComponent() {
    print('inside constructor, text = $text'); // $text is null.
  }

}

class Token {
  String char;
  bool important;
  Token(this.char, this.important);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to ave the component implement `NgAttachAware` and define the `attach()` method. The value of the derived field can then be set inside `attach()`. I have no idea if there is a more idiomatic way to do this, but using `attach()` seems to work.

Here is the code:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'tokens',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    cssUrl: './component.css',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const {
      'text' : '@text'
    }
)
class TokensComponent implements NgAttachAware {
  String text;

  // Derived field.
  List<Token> tokens = new List<Token>();

  TokensComponent() {
    print('inside constructor, text = $text');
  }

  void attach() {
    print('inside attach(), text = $text'); // $text is no longer null.
    text.split('').forEach((char) => tokens.add(new Token(char, false)));
  }
}

class Token {
  String char;
  bool important;
  Token(this.char, this.important);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The current best practice for derived fields is to calculate them on-demand and cache the results.  By waiting, the app may be able to avoid unneeded work when the derived field isn't being used.

e.g. your example component would look like:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'tokens',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    cssUrl: './component.css',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const {
      'text' : '@text'
    }
)
class TokensComponent {
  Map<bool, List<Token>> _tokensCache = new Map<bool, List<Token>>();

  String _text;
  get text => _text;
  set text(t) {
    _text = t;
    _tokensCache.clear();  // invalidate the cache any time text changes.
  }

  // Derived field.
  List<Token> get tokens =>
    text == null ? [] : _tokensCache.putIfAbsent(true,
        () => text.split('').map((char) =>  new Token(char, false)));

}
```

Now, tokens is always up-to-date, and if nothing ever asks for tokens, the component doesn't compute that field.

In this example, the cache is required. Since Angular's dirty checking uses `identical` to check for changes, our component must return an identical tokens list if the component has not changed.