# is it possible to access attributes set in HTML in an angular.dart constructor?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I cann´t access the attribute val in the constructor of this component

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'dartcomp',
    templateUrl: 'dartComp.html',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const
    { 
      'val' : '@val'
    }
)
class DartComp
{ String val;

  DartComp()
  { print("construktor DartComp $val");
  }
}
```

which was used in index.html

```
<dartcomp id="dc" val="x"></dartcomp>
```

Is there a way to access val in the constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating derived fields in an Angular Dart component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080837/populating-derived-fields-in-an-angular-dart-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `NgAttachAware`, implement the method `attach()` and access your field there. When `attach()` is called your `val` is already properly initialized.

Comment: tnx, do you have a link where AttachAware is described?

Comment: http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core/NgAttachAware.html