# Component Attribute is none - timing issue

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to do a HTTPRequest based upon a url, which is set in a component attribute. I tried it like shown below, but the dataUrl is always none. It seems as the constructor of the component is executed before the attributes, which are set in the html, are available to the component.

How can I tell the HTTPRequest to wait until the dataUrl variable is available?

component.dart

```dart
class TableData {

  static List data = [];

  TableData() {}

  //GETTERS
  List get getData => data;
}


@NgComponent(
    selector: 'jstable',
    templateUrl: 'jstable/jstable_component.html',
    cssUrl: 'jstable/jstable_component.css',
    publishAs: 'cmp'
)
class JSTableComponent {
  @NgAttr('name')
  String name;

  @NgAttr('data-url')
  String dataUrl;

  TableData _table_data = new TableData();

  final Http _http;
  bool dataLoaded = false;

  JSTableComponent(this._http) {
    _loadData().then((_) {
      dataLoaded = true;
    }, onError: (_) {
      dataLoaded = false;
    });
  }
  //GETTERS
  List get data => _table_data.getData;

  //HTTP
  Future _loadData() {
    print("data url is");
    print(dataUrl);
    return _http.get(dataUrl).then((HttpResponse response) {
      TableData.data = response.data['data'];
    });
  }
}
```

.html

```dart
<jstable name="myjstablename" data-url="table-data.json"></jstable>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to access attributes set in HTML in an angular.dart constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172775/is-it-possible-to-access-attributes-set-in-html-in-an-angular-dart-constructor)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080837  
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `NgAttachAware` and put your code in the `attach` method. The attributes are already evaluated when `attach` is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would leave the question open as it is not in general about accessing the attributes, but about the initialisation timing.